# How to merge mostly duplicated rows

Tags: python, duplicates, pandas, dataframe

Some of my data looks like:

```
date, name, value1, value2, value3, value4
1/1/2001,ABC,1,1,,
1/1/2001,ABC,,,2,
1/1/2001,ABC,,,,35
```

I am trying to get to the point where I can run

```
data.set_index(['date', 'name'])
```

But, with the data as-is, there are of course duplicates (as shown in the above), so I cannot do this (and I don't want an index with duplicates, and I can't simply drop_duplicates(), since this would lose data).

I would like to be able to force rows which have the same [date, name] values into a single rows, if they can be successfully converged based on certain values being NaN (similar to the behavior of combine_first()).  E.g., the above would end up at

```
date, name, value1, value2, value3, value4
1/1/2001,ABC,1,1,2,35
```

If two values are different and one is not NaN, the two rows should not be converged (this would probably be an error that I would need to follow up on).

(To extend the above example, there may in fact be an arbitrary number of lines--given an arbitrary number of columns--which should be able to be converged into one single line.)

This feels like a problem that should be very solvable via pandas, but I am having trouble figuring out an elegant solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's imagine you have some function `combine_it` that, given a set of rows that would have duplicate values, returns a single row. First, group by `date` and `name`:

```
grouped = data.groupby(['date', 'name'])
```

Then just apply the aggregation function and *boom* you're done:

```
result = grouped.agg(combine_it)
```

You can also provide different aggregation functions for different columns by passing `agg` a dict.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely cuts down a key step.  Is there a particularly efficient idiom to do this with?  In my experience (and initial testing using your suggestion), .agg() can result in really slow execution (probably unsurprisingly).  Maybe unavoidable?

Comment: Maybe? You could try using builtin numpy functions ("sum", "max", etc.) to speed it up (which uses cythonized functions). This is likely outside of the normal use case for groupby because you probably end up with many groups relative to the total size of the DataFrame.

Comment: Well, barring another answer, at least I know I haven't missed anything too obvious...

Comment: @severian yup, `combine_it` is the slow thing not agg.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have numeric field values, aggregating with count, min, sum etc. will not be neither possible nor sensible. Nevertheless, you still may want to collapse duplicate records to individual records (e.g.) based on one or more  primary keys.

```
# Firstly, avoid Nan values in the columns you are grouping on!
df[['col1', 'col2']] =  df[['col1', 'col2']].fillna('null')


  # Define your own customized operation in pandas agg() function
df = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).agg({'SEARCH_TERM':lambda x: ', '.join(tuple(x.tolist())),

                                     'HITS_CONTENT':lambda x: ', '.join(tuple(x.tolist()))}
                                   )
```

Group by one or more columns and collapse values values by converting them first, to list, then to tuple and finally to string. If you prefer you can also keep them as list or tuple stored in each field or apply with the agg. function and a dictionary very different operations to different columns.

Answer (score 1):

Since your column-wise values are not repeated then you can use the trick of `agg` function like this:

```
data.groupby(['date', 'name']).agg('sum')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = df.groupby(["date", "name"])
df1 = df1.apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates()
print(df1.head())

       date name  value1  value2  value3  value4
0  1/1/2001  ABC     1.0     1.0     2.0    35.0
```

Per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45599151/1154981