# How to combine sparse rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So lets say I have a pandas data frame:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

...

In [4]: df

Out[3]:
  Person_ID First_Name Last_Name  Phone_Number              Email
1      A456       John       Doe          None               None
2      A456       John       Doe  123-123-1234  john.doe@test.com
3      A890        Joe      Dirt  321-321-4321               None
4      A890        Joe      Dirt          None      joe@email.com
```

and I would like to cook up some transformation to turn it into this:

```
  Person_ID First_Name Last_Name  Phone_Number              Email
1      A456       John       Doe  123-123-1234  john.doe@test.com
2      A890        Joe      Dirt  321-321-4321      joe@email.com
```

i.e. I would like to be able to take a data frame which may have multiple rows of data corresponding to the same person (and sharing a Person_ID) but missing entries in different places and combine those entries intro a row containing all of the information.

Importantly, this is not just a task of filtering out the rows with more `None` values in them as for instance in my toy example, line 3 and 4 have an equal number of `None`'s but the data is populated in different places.

Would anyone have advice on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with methods `ffill` and `bfill` and then [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Person_ID').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates()
print (df1)
  Person_ID First_Name Last_Name  Phone_Number              Email
1      A456       John       Doe  123-123-1234  john.doe@test.com
3      A890        Joe      Dirt  321-321-4321      joe@email.com
```

Comment: Wow that was fast!  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
In [1571]: df.groupby('Person_ID', as_index=False).apply(
                      lambda x: x.ffill().bfill().iloc[0])
Out[1571]:
  Person_ID First_Name Last_Name  Phone_Number              Email
0      A456       John       Doe  123-123-1234  john.doe@test.com
1      A890        Joe      Dirt  321-321-4321      joe@email.com
```

Comment: Do we need both`ffill` and `bfill`  ?